# Autofac and scope issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

Ok, this is starting to get on my nerves. I wish I had never started using Autofac, it has just become too difficult to use.

I have created a Module and I have set it up in the following way:

- All services that do not require database interaction have been set
  up as Singletons. These are generally the helper classes like the
  **EncryptionProvider**, etc.
- All services injected into controllers have been set up as **InstancePerRequest** for obvious reasons.
- Any service that is injected into a controller service has been set up as **InstancePerDependency**.

I think that is the correct way to do things. And in theory it should work.
Now, in comes the "complications".

- First off, the **DbContext**, I have looked about and I set this up as **InstancePerDependency** following my rules above.
- Then I set up my **OAuthProvider, UserManager and RefreshTokenService**. My rules above would set the latter 2 as **InstancePerRequest**, but the RefreshTokenService and OAuthProvider (which has the UserManager injected into it) are needed in **Startup.cs**:

  ```
  var config = new HttpConfiguration();
  var scope = config.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();

  // Get our providers
  var authProvider = scope.Resolve<OAuthProvider>();
  var refreshTokenProvider = scope.Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();

  // Create our OAuth options
  return new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
  {
      AllowInsecureHttp = true, // TODO: Remove this line
      TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/access_token"),
      AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
      AccessTokenFormat = new Business.Authentication.JwtFormat("http://localhost:62668"),
      Provider = authProvider,
      RefreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider
  };
  ```

I did have all three set to **InstancePerLifetimeScope** but it was causing issues because **UserManager**.
So I then set them to **InstancePerDependency** and everything compiled, but I found that nothing was saving...

I really need to figure out how to do this before my manager tells me to remove Autofac. So, can anyone out there tell me how I should be registering the 3 problematic services?

Comment: Try and find out which thing hasn't got the lifetime you are expecting it to have, and post back with specifics.
I often temporarily put
private static int nextId;
private int id = nextId++
in classes, so I can debug how many of a class there have been.
If something is living longer than you expect, is it because it is in turn a dependency of something with longer lifetime?
e.g. if MySingleton depends on MyTransientClass, then MyTransientClass will not actually be transient, because it is only recreated when MySingleton needs it, which is only once.